# How to insert json data in table ORACLE?

Tags: python, json, oracle, cx-oracle

Tell me how to insert data from a json file into a table? I have a TESDB table and there are 2 columns LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME.I wanted inserting all JSON data into a table. Please tell me how to do this correctly? Thank you in advance

Json file:

```
[{'LAST_NAME': 'Alex', 'FIRST_NAME': 'Pip'}, {'LAST_NAME': 'John', 'FIRST_NAME': 'Alan'}, {'LAST_NAME': 'Dehan', 'FIRST_NAME': 'Luck'}, {'LAST_NAME': 'Nick', 'FIRST_NAME': 'Adem'}, {'LAST_NAME': 'Aspen', 'FIRST_NAME': 'Turit'}]
```

Python code:

```
with open('object.json') as f:
    json_obj = json.load(f)
print(json_obj)

for i,item in enumerate(json_obj):
    LAST_NAME = (item.get("LAST_NAME", None))
    FIRST_NAME =(item.get("FIRST_NAME", None))
cursor.execute("insert into TESTDB (LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME) VALUES (:1,:2)", (LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME))
conn.close
```

Comment: What specific problem/error are you having?

Comment: What's the table description - what are the column datatypes?